# Can't access the lower rows with LIMIT OFFSET

Tags: php, mysql, select, join, count

My table structure is as follows.

```
users
ID      name

comments
ID      post_id     comment

product
pid     views   post_id     filesize    upload_date

product_group
gid     views   post_id         group_category

product_category
cid     views   post_id
```

I want to get all the users(even those who haven't uploaded any product) with their uploaded product number, ordered by their uploaded product number. I also need to get number of comments, number of views of the all the product of a user, last upload date etc.

I have come with the following query.

```sql
    (SELECT COUNT(product.pid) AS p_num,
            SUM(product.views) AS views,
            COUNT(comments.ID) AS comment,
            SUM(product.filesize) AS size,
            MAX(product.upload_date) AS date,
            users.*
    FROM users
    LEFT JOIN product ON users.ID = product.uploader AND exclude =0
    LEFT JOIN product_group ON product_group.gid = product.groupid AND product_group.group_category =0
    LEFT JOIN comments ON product.post_id = comments.ID
    WHERE product_group.gid IS NULL AND users.ID = "Current user id")
    UNION
    (SELECT COUNT(product.pid) AS p_num,
            SUM(product.views) AS views,
            COUNT(comments.ID) AS comment,
            SUM(product.filesize) AS size,
            MAX(product.upload_date) AS date,
            users.* FROM
            users
    LEFT JOIN product ON users.ID = uploader AND exclude =0
    LEFT JOIN product_group ON gid = product.groupid AND product_group.group_category =0
    LEFT JOIN comments ON product.post_id = comments.ID
    WHERE product_group.gid IS NULL
    GROUP BY users.ID
    ORDER BY p_num DESC
    LIMIT 24 OFFSET 0)
```

The first select is to keep current user at top in all pages.

The query works perfectly if I don't give any LIMIT OFFSET clause.

It returns 964 rows, the total number of user in my database. I have checked comments, upload_date. These are also returned correctly.

But if I try the same query with `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 950`, it returns empty result set.
It seems that it returns 947 rows this way. I don't understand what is going on here.

Comment: Is limit and offset supposed to be applied to the second query only? It is inside the parentheses.

Comment: @GolezTrol The first query will always return 1 row. The second query return 964 rows. So, I believe LIMIT and OFFSET applies to second query only.